# Outlier detection- univariate vs multivariate

Tags: outliers

One gets different results upon using a univariate approach (boxplot) vs using a multivariate approach (Cook's distance). Which is more advisable ? Univariate boxplots are pretty easy to use but one can end up misjudging observations.

Comment: "More advisable" for what purpose, exactly?

Comment: @whuber I used boxplots (univariate) to detect outliers in the chronic kidney disease dataset (UCI repo). But such a method does not take into consideration the relationship of that particular variable with other variables in the dataset. Some of those observations might not need to be touched.
I came across Cook's distance recently. However, a univarate box plot and Cook's yielded different answers. How do I go about using both to come to a conclusion on which observations to choose as outliers that need to be treated ?
I hope that I was able to be more clear.

Comment: That explains *what* you are doing, but doesn't really explain *why*. One identifies and treats outliers for various purposes: what is yours?  What criteria should be applied when determining what might be "advisable" or not?

Comment: example- in the, variable blood pressure, the boxplot gave multiplie outlier values of 100, 120, 180. However, when I compared them with the factor variable for hypertension (1 or 0), I saw that a bp of 180 had a corresponding value of 1 (has hypertension), which makes sense. But there were bp values of 100 that had values of both 1 and 0. So, I got a confused whether it is simply enough to just limit focus to one variable.  I hope that I am asking the right questions. I am new to all this.